# Edge contraction $K_4$

Tags: graph-theory

Is this how an edge contraction on $K_4$ looks like?

[image]

Comment: Edge contractions should remove only a single edge, and the total number of edges has somehow decreased by two. That is, unless you are removing duplicate edges, but since your final graph has a duplicate edge, I'd guess that this isn't what you're doing.

Comment: But if it only removes a single edge, what is the difference between removing an edge and contracting an edge then?

Comment: Oh contraction removes a vertex as well right? But how can I remove a vertex while only removing one edge? Can you just show me how to do it?

Comment: You take an edge, and its two vertices, and merge them into one vertex. Any other edge that ends at one of these two vertices will now end at the new vertex, possibly creating doubled edges. Every other edge and vertex remains untouched. If you pick any edge of $K_4$, there will be two other vertices, each adjacent to both the merging vertices. So, the new vertex needs **two** edges to each of the other vertices. In other words, you get a triangle with two doubled edges, not one.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm stupid :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the kind of graph you get.

[image]